# Como alterar o formato da data no SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, data

Atualmente meu banco esta em formato AAAA-DD-MM gostaria de por em MM-DD-AAAA.

Encontrei o `SET DATEFORMAT` só que não é a melhor opção visto que terei que acrescentá-lo em todas as *querys*.

É possível eu configurá-lo na minha conexão semelhante ao que é feito no MySQL?? Ou mudar em isso em algum lugar pra eu não precisar alterar nas *querys*?

Comment: Não entendi o seu objetivo. Você quer usar literais para representar datas (ex: `2014-04-28`) ou quer imprimir as datas de alguma forma?

Answer (score 3):

Se a ideia é usar literais de datas nas queries, apenas use o formato ISO: `YYYY-MM-DD` (ano, mês e dia). Isso será interpretado sem problemas em qualquer ambiente.

Para  formatar (ou "imprimir") datas para texto no formato `MM/DD/AAAA` você pode usar a função [`CONVERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Exemplo:

```
select convert(varchar, coluna_date, 101)
```

O mesmo é válido para converter texto no formato especificado para uma data:

```
select convert(datetime, coluna_varchar, 101)
```

Comment: Meu caro essa é uma alternativa, porém não das melhores visto que terei que alterar todo o script que tem mais de 500 consultas.  Pensava em poder setar uma determinada configuração em algum lugar e assim sanar o problema.

Comment: @IagoLeão Esta é a forma correta de implementar para tornar o script independente da localidade do servidor. Se o seu script tem tantas conversões *hardcoded*, você tem 3 alternativas: (1) alterar tudo (já pensou em usar REGEX para automatizar isso?); (2) se os scripts são executados via sistema, adicionar um comando `SET DATEFORMT` ao obter a conexão; (3) alterar a linguagem padrão do servidor ([ver este link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/11/13/how-to-change-date-format-after-installing-sql-server.aspx), em inglês).

Comment: no código existia 'cast((convert(char(10),@perfim,101)+ ' 11:59:59 pm') as datetime)' só que isso gera este erro Exception (0x80131904): A conversão de um tipo de dados varchar em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo.
A instrução foi finalizada.] então retirei o cast convert e passei a data no formato YYYY-MM-AA passando a funcionar, só tem um lugar que continua dando este mesmo erro mesmo com a alteração supracitada. Penso então se não será menos custoso aplicar a 2° ou a 3° sugestão.

Comment: @IagoLeão Estou vendo que tem muita manipulação "manual" de datas. O erro de "valor fora do intervalo" ocorre quando a data está em formato incorreto, por exemplo quando se tenta ler um número maior que 12 como o mês da data. Imagino que esse horário sendo somado aí seria para fazer uma comparação de intervalo de datas, certo? Existem outras maneiras de fazer isso. Já pensou em criar uma `FUNCTION` para encapsular essas coisas e tornar a manutenção mais fácil?

Comment: este é um código de terceiros, no qual o nosso cliente solicitou que fizéssemos uma migração visto que a outra empresa parou de dar suporte, nós não iremos melhorar o e absolutamente nunca iremos fazer qualquer implementação, visto isso buscamos a solução mais fácil e não a melhor, não sei se me entende.

Comment: @IagoLeão Entendo, sim, e entendo a dor de cabeça que deve estar dando. Se a migração for do tipo que se "faz uma vez e pronto", sugiro alterar a linguagem do SQL Server (opção #3). Caso contrário sugiro fazer os asjutes conforme a opção #1. Há também a opção de fazer uma expressão regular para adicionar automaticamente o `SET DATEFORMAT` no início de todas as rotinas.

Comment: desculpa mais uma vez incomodar. Conseguir resolver aquele problema de data em vários lugares, mas restou dois nos quais não foi nem a pau. Poderia me ajudar?

Comment: @IagoLeão Se for possível isolar exemplos disso, poste uma nova pergunta que eu dou uma olhada.