# Formatar retorno de data e hora PT BR no PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, strtotime

Estou usando a função *strtotime* do *PHP* para formatar a data que vêm no banco de dados *SQL SERVER* e está funcionando normalmente no servidor local, porém na web retorna a data 12-31-1969 21:00 PM. Alguém sabe o motivo?

(Como está gravado no banco) = Jan 31 2017 4:36PM

```
$timestamp = $row['DtPedido'];
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($timestamp)); 
//imprime 31/01/2017 16:36:00  (LOCAL - CORRETO)
//imprime 12-31-1969 21:00:00  (WEB)
```

Comment: Não seria mais simples já mandar formatada a data? veja [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88778/91) ou [essa outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14228/91)

Comment: O melhor seria arrumar o banco, e usar um campo data sem formatação visual. No manual do strtotime tem as regras de interpretação de data, e se não quer depender de locale, precisa usar formato yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: Seria mais fácil mandar formatado mas não tenho acesso aos inserts e toda a base está neste formato. Vou verificar o manual do strtotime.

Comment: @denis no pior dos casos você pode quebrar a string em espaços e rearranjar antes de jogar no strtotime, ou mesmo usar outra função. Está longe de ser o ideal, mas pode te dar algum controle maior.

Comment: @denis vc poderia dá um `var_dump($timestamp)` e me informar o resultado tanto no servidor qnt no localhost?

Answer (score 3):

O formato apresentado na pergunta possui os seguintes símbolos:

*M d Y H:iA*

```
M -> Representação textual do mês, abreviado
d -> Dia, 2 dígitos
Y -> Ano, 4 dígitos
H -> Hora, 2 dígitos
i -> Minuto, 2 dígitos
A -> Período em letra maiúscula (AM/PM)
```

Com isso, pode informar a sequência dos símbolos para alguma função de formatação de datas.

No exemplo abaixo, o método `createFromFormat()` da classe `DateTime`:

```
$str = 'Jan 31 2017 4:36PM';
if ($date = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d Y H:iA', $str)) {
    //echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Formato ISO 8601
    echo $date->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'); // O formato que você quer.
}
```

É bom verificar se o retorno de `DateTime::createFromFormat` é válido. Caso contrário, poderá causar fatal error quando invocar o método `format()` de um objeto faltoso.

<sub>Nota: A classe DateTime é disponível a partir do PHP5.3</sub>

**Alternativamente**, pode fazer a formatação com as funções `date()` e `strtotime()`.

```
$str = 'Jan 31 2017 4:36PM';
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($str));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Funciona normalmente no servidor local que uso (Scriptcase) mas no sevidor UOL na Web dá esse erro Call to undefined method DateTime::createFromFormat(). Na real tudo que testo funciona local e na Web não. Deve ser a versão do PHP do UOL sei lá .. obrigado mesmo assim vou continuar os testes

Comment: Pois é ! Obrigado mesmo assim !

Answer (score 1):

Pelo fato do servidor não ter suporte a várias funções por usar versão do *PHP* antiga, vou postar como resolvi para eventualmente ajudar alguém que possa ter o mesmo problema. Como diz o amigo Daniel, não é a melhor solução, mas fica mais amigável de mostrar a data.

```
$timestamp = $row['DtPedido'];
$sliceDt = explode(" ",  $timestamp);
$sliceH = explode("  ",  $timestamp);
$data =  $sliceDt[1]." de ".$sliceDt[0]." de ".$sliceDt[2] . " - ".$sliceH[1];  
//imprime 31 de Jan de 2017 - 4:36PM
```